# Can't remove 5px gap it table between two images inside a table

Tags: html, css, html-email

I can't seem to get these two images to sit right on top of each other. They are both in there own rows in a HTML table (I'm making a html email) but I can't seem to remove the 5px between them.

Here is my code

```
<table width="200" height="200" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-    spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;border-collapse: seperate;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="100" height="100"><img width="100" height="100" src="https://img.createsend1.com/img/templatebuilder/placeholder-image.png" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100" height="100"><img width="100" height="100" src="https://img.createsend1.com/img/templatebuilder/placeholder-image.png" /> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>​
```

its also on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JpdQ2/1/) if that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the images to `vertical-align: top`.  By default they are `baseline` which leaves space below the image for characters in text which are below the baseline.  Pretty much any value other than `baseline` should work (bottom, middle, etc.).

```
img{
  vertical-align: top;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JpdQ2/2/

Answer (score 2):

Or, set the images to `display: block`. Inline images always have spacing issues due to the vertical alignment.

http://jsfiddle.net/JpdQ2/3/

Comment: Might be worth noting that this could cause line breaks which may not be desired, assuming the actual html is more complicated than just these two images.